# In pentaho how can I ignore a not well formed XML file and continue with the rest

Tags: xml, pentaho, kettle

In pentaho, is there a way to ignore a not well formed XML file and continue the transformation on the rest of the well formed (valid) XML files.

I tried the define error handling but this didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following `Check if XML file is well formed` step. Actually that step is available in a job. So what you have to do is add the transformation to a job and use the following step as necessary in the job.

[image]

In the advanced tab of the step includes an option `Result file name` You can select `Add only well formed file names`

Comment: I can't seem to find this step?  I'm using version 5.3

Comment: That step is available in a job. I updated my answer

Comment: I really could not find this job. Am I missing something here. I searched for it, it is not available. http://postimg.org/image/gqultyf1t/

Comment: no you have to create a new job. In that under XML you can find the step. refer http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fpdi_user_guide%2Freference_entry_check_xml_form.html

Comment: Thanks, that's it!, sorry I'm new to pentaho.

Answer (score 1):

Is not the same xml well formed (handled by xsd definitions) or xml broken.

If you are having **parsing** errors from pentaho i am afraid **your xml is broken**. For instance: if the xml contains illegal characters like **&** without **CDATA block**, no xml parser in the world will be able to parse without error and halt. **And this is how should be.**

I would suggest to fix the xml, if the xml cames from third parties, send an email : your xml is broken, fix it.

Hope you understand that an xml not well formed (handled by xsd definitions) is not the same as an xml broken.

Comment: I started working on pre-processing the XML. If not well formed then fix it (same structure as the rest).

Comment: ok, so the xml is legal, but not follows your xsd definition?